# return response with nested Json format

Tags: json, rest, yii2

I am trying to get my response as nested json format

```
[  
   {  
      "recipe_id":"33",
      "e_name":"crispy",
      "e_desc":"Crispy Gingersnaps",
      "calries":"500",
      "steps":[  
         {  
            "step_id":"22",
            "recipe_id":"33",
            "step_number":3,
            "instruction":'here is the instructions',            
         }
         {  
            "step_id":"23",
            "recipe_id":"34",
            "step_number":4,
            "instruction":'here is the instructions',            
         }
        {  
            "step_id":"23",
            "recipe_id":"35",
            "step_number":5,
            "instruction":'here is the instructions',            
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

this is my code

```
$query  = new \yii\db\Query();
            $recipes = $query->select(['recipe.recipe_id','recipe.image','recipe.'.$name,'recipe.'.$small_desc,'recipe.person_count',
            'recipe.calories','recipe.period','recipe.'.$desc,'recipe_step.instruction'])->from('recipe')
            ->where(['recipe.recipe_id' => $recipe_id])            
            ->innerJoin("recipe_step","recipe.recipe_id=recipe_step.recipe_id");
```

i get the result but json format not like what i expect

Comment: Please share the results which you get

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is such an option to implement this behavior with query only. But you can implement recept relation to steps relations and add steps with yii2 methods.

Recipe model

```
public function getStep()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Step::className(), ['recipe_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Where you want it to get:

```
$model = Recipe::find()->where([Recipe::tableName() . '.id' => $recipe_id])->innerJoin('step')->asArray()->one();
```

As a result you get data structure you have described.

Answer (score -1):

You need to execute the query with all(), to get the results that you expect, at it at the end of the query.

```
 $recipes = $query->select(['recipe.recipe_id','recipe.image','recipe.'.$name,'recipe.'.$small_desc,'recipe.person_count',
        'recipe.calories','recipe.period','recipe.'.$desc,'recipe_step.instruction'])->from('recipe')
        ->where(['recipe.recipe_id' => $recipe_id])            
        ->innerJoin("recipe_step","recipe.recipe_id=recipe_step.recipe_id")->all();
```